# Gaussian Blur implementation not working properly

Tags: c#, image-processing, gaussian

I'm attempting to implement a simple Gaussian Blur function, however when run on the image, it just comes back as more opaque than the original; no blur takes place.

```
    public double[,] CreateGaussianFilter(int size)
    {
        double[,] gKernel = new double[size,size];

        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
                gKernel[y,x] = 0.0;

        // set standard deviation to 1.0
        double sigma = 1.0;
        double r, s = 2.0 * sigma * sigma;

        // sum is for normalization
        double sum = 0.0;

        // generate kernel
        for (int x = -size/2; x <= size/2; x++)
        {
            for(int y = -size/2; y <= size/2; y++)
            {
                r = Math.Sqrt(x*x + y*y);
                gKernel[x + size/2, y + size/2] = (Math.Exp(-(r*r)/s))/(Math.PI * s);
                sum += gKernel[x + size/2, y + size/2];
            }
        }

        // normalize the Kernel
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
                gKernel[i,j] /= sum;

        return gKernel;
    }

    public void GaussianFilter(ref LockBitmap image, double[,] filter)
    {
        int size = filter.GetLength(0);
        for (int y = size/2; y < image.Height - size/2; y++)
        {
            for (int x = size/2; x < image.Width - size/2; x++)
            {
                //Grab surrounding pixels and stick them in an accumulator
                double sum = 0.0;
                int filter_y = 0;
                for (int r = y - (size / 2); r < y + (size / 2); r++)
                {
                    int filter_x = 0;
                    for (int c = x - (size / 2); c < x + (size / 2); c++)
                    {
                        //Multiple surrounding pixels by filter, add them up and set the center pixel (x,y) to this value
                        Color pixelVal = image.GetPixel(c, r);
                        double grayVal = (pixelVal.B + pixelVal.R + pixelVal.G) / 3.0;
                        sum += grayVal * filter[filter_y,filter_x];
                        filter_x++;
                    }
                    filter_y++;
                }
                //set the xy pixel 
                image.SetPixel(x,y, Color.FromArgb(255, (int)sum,(int)sum, (int)sum));
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of things about your solution.

1. A convolved image getting darker generally means there is a gain in the kernel of less than 1. Though perhaps not in this case, see (5).
2. Gaussian blur is a separable kernel and can be performed in far less time than brute force.
3. Averaging RGB to gray is not an optically "correct" means of computing luminance.
4. getpixel, setpixel approaches are generally very slow. If you are in a language supporting pointers you should use them. Looks like C#? Use unsafe code to get access to pointers.
5. int() truncates - this could be your source of decreased brightness. You are in essence always rounding down.
6. Your nested loops in the kernel generating function contain excessive bounds adjustments. This could be much faster but better yet replaced with a separable approach.
7. You are convolving in a single buffer. Therefore you are convolving convoved values.

Thanks